# Establishing the action of a self referencing function in a python script

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to understand a piece of code (I can't post the actual code) which contains a function that references itself within it's code, it doesn't seem to be recursive and I can't work out its effect.
An example of what I mean is below:

```
def function(self):
    if self.property == 1:
        a = self.object1.function
    elif self.property == 2:
        a = self.object1.function + self.object2.function
```

This may be really obvious, but I can't see it, I've read a lot of the previous questions on recursive functions or self referential functions, but I can't find anything structured along these lines, thanks!

Comment: Adding two functions (as opposed to what they compute)?  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Is the function  a [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)? Then accessing the `function` attribute will invoke `function()`.

Comment: It is an @property, sorry should have noticed that, haven't come across the notation before, and didn't realize it could affect the function (I'm assuming it can, it's the line before the function starts)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this function is part of a class which is a recursive data structure, such a as a Tree that has children nodes. In this case, each instance has at least two children `object1` and `object2`.

You are correct to assume that this `function` is not calling itself (recursive), but rather it is calling the `function` method on it's children.

At some point, `function` is going to return either a string or number; assuming because the `+` if `self.property == 2`.

Again, this resembles a Tree data structure.

`class Tree():
    def __init__(left, property, right):
        self.property = property
        self.object1 = left
        self.object2 = right`

Comment: Turns out that the 'function' term inside the main function was simply an attribute of the object (which belonged to a custom class) with the same name as the function. 
So the main function called the attribute which was an integer, which it could then add together.
Sorry for the confusion, just didn't expect the function to have been given the same name as the attribute it called.

Comment: Ah. Sound good. Sounds like a simple attribute rename would help relieve some confusion. Thanks for updating.